# JavaScript - multiple canvas cleaning function

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hello i have this function in my project to clean all 9 canvases and selects assigned to click button. I use the method of getting canvas by ID and then getting context + cleaning it by clearRect in many other functions and there is no problem with it but here it just doesn´t work and log says - no canvas specified. (be kind to me i´m total JS noob :)

```
function cleanup() {

    setSelectValue('gtr', 'no');
    setSelectValue('color', 'no');
    setSelectValue('board', 'no');
    setSelectValue('in', 'no');
    setSelectValue('bind', 'no');
    setSelectValue('head', 'no');
    setSelectValue('pick', 'no');
    setSelectValue('tuner', 'no');
    setSelectValue('pot', 'no');
    setSelectValue('hw', 'no');
    setSelectValue('switch', 'no');

    var can = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var c = can.getContext('2d');
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var can1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
    var c1 = can1.getContext('2d');
    c1.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var can2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
    var c2 = can2.getContext('2d');
    c2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var can3 = document.getElementById('myCanvas3');
    var c3 = can3.getContext('2d');
    c3.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var can4 = document.getElementById('myCanvas4');
    var c4 = can4.getContext('2d');
    c4.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var can5 = document.getElementById('myCanvas5');
    var c5 = can5.getContext('2d');
    c5.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var can6 = document.getElementById('myCanvas6');
    var c6 = can6.getContext('2d');
    c6.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var can7 = document.getElementById('myCanvas7');
    var c7 = can7.getContext('2d');
    c7.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var can8 = document.getElementById('myCanvas8');
    var c8 = can8.getContext('2d');
    c8.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Answer (score 0):

**Your code has typos:**

```
// in each clearRect use can1.width, can1.height
// instead of canvas.width, canvas.height

var can1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
var c1 = can1.getContext('2d');
c1.clearRect(0, 0, can1.width, can1.height);  // not canvas.width, canvas.height
```

**Alternatively...**

One easy way to clear all canvases is to put references to all canvases in an array.  Also put references to all contexts in another array.

Then you can just iterate those arrays in your cleanup() function and clear the canvases.

```
// save each canvas and context in arrays
var canvases=[];
var contexts=[];

// save all canvases and contexts in arrays
var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas"):
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
canvases.push(canvas);
contexts.push(context);
//
for(var i=1;i<9,i++){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas"+i):
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvases.push(canvas);
    contexts.push(context);
}

// clear all canvases
function cleanup(){
    for(var i=0;i<contexts.length;i++){
        contexts[i].clearRect(0,0,canvases[i].width,canvases[i].height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clear all the canvases in your page you can do something like this:

```
for(var i = 0, c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas'); i < c.length; i++)
    c[i].getContext('2d').clearRect(0,0,c[i].width, c[i].height);
```

Short break-down:

The:

```
c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
```

is listing all available canvases in your page as an HTMLCollection (sort of array).

Then loop though that array using index which is the current canvas element itself, get context for that canvas and clear:

A more "clean-code" version doing the same could look like this, wrapped up in a reusable function:

```
function clearAllCanvases() {

    var i = 0, canvas,
        canvases = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')

    for(; canvas = canvases[i++];) {
        canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
}
```